# Add label on ggplot2 based on the trend behavior

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyquant

I have a time series and calculated two trends based on stock price. I am trying to add label like **˄** on the plot when SMA.15 (blue line) crossover SMA.15 (red line)

```
AAPL %>%
    select(date, close, SMA.15, SMA.50) %>%
    gather(key = type, value = price, close:SMA.50) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = price, col = type)) +
    geom_line() +
    theme(legend.position="bottom") +
    ggtitle("Simple Moving Averages with tidyquant") +
    xlab("") + 
    ylab("Stock Price")
```

[image]

Comment: Calculate the position of the point, then use `+ annotate("text", x = ..., y = ..., label = "^")`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using the `ggplot2::economics` dataset. I scale the values so they make sense to plot together, and smooth with a rolling mean. You can then see some candidate intersections by finding dates where the variables are close. Here I pick the second row and add a small y adjustment so the `^` is pointing at the intersection rather than on top of it.

```r
library(tidyverse)
ts <- economics %>%
  mutate_at(vars(psavert, pce, unemploy), ~ `attributes<-`(scale(.), NULL)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(psavert, pce, unemploy), ~ RcppRoll::roll_mean(., 5, fill = NA)) %>%
  select(date, psavert, pce, unemploy)

pts <- ts %>%
  mutate(diff = abs(pce - unemploy)) %>%
  arrange(diff)
head(pts, 3)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   date       psavert     pce unemploy     diff
#>   <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 1988-07-01 -0.0181 -0.415   -0.415  0.000596
#> 2 2012-08-01 -0.383   1.75     1.76   0.00191 
#> 3 1994-09-01 -0.530  -0.0122  -0.0180 0.00577

ggplot(ts %>% gather(type, value, psavert:unemploy)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = value, col = type)) +
  annotate("text", x = pts$date[2], y = pts$pce[2] - 0.1, label = "^")
#> Warning: Removed 12 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).